# Solr: fuzzy operator not changing search results

Tags: solr, django-views, fuzzy-search

If at all possible, I'd like to restrict my code changes to just `schema.xml` and other configuration files. I have the following code in my `schema.xml`:

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" /> 
<field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="fact" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="body" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<copyField source="title" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="body" dest="text"/>
```

I have defined text_exact_fuzzy later in my `schema.xml` as follows:

```
<text_exact_fuzzy: field type for fuzzy matching -->
<fieldType name="text_exact_fuzzy" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
 <analyzer type="index">
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15"/>
 </analyzer>
 <analyzer type="query">
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  <!--
  <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  -->
  <filter class="solr.PhoneticFilterFactory" encoder="DoubleMetaphone" inject="true"/>
 </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

When I make a query in a Django view, I use the following code (which takes the query and appends the tilde notation (e.g. ~0.8) to the end of each word in the query):

```
fuzzy_clean_text = re.sub(r'\s', '~' + str(fuzzy_index) + ' ', clean_text + ' ')
#return fuzzy_clean_text
post_params = [('q', re.escape(json.dumps(fuzzy_clean_text))),
               ('wt','json'),
               ('fl', 'fact'),
               # I've tried the query with and without the following parameter:
               #('spellcheck.collate', 'true'),
            ]
result = urllib2.urlopen(solr_server_url, urllib.urlencode(post_params))
response = json.loads(result.read())
```

However, no matter how I set the `fuzzy_index`, the query returns the same results. In addition, the fuzzy search is very lenient, sometimes matching irrelevant text to particular `fact`s. Is there another approach, either through query parameters or modifications to the `schema.xml` file that would correct the issue? Other stackoverflow posts suggest `ComplexPhraseQueryParser`, but I don't want to be adding Java to my codebase (and it seems pretty difficult to understand anyway).

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the solution to the same problem. After going through few documentations and mailer forums, I realized there is no in-built method in solr to achieve this directly.
Though this method is not a very clean and efficient one, here is how I have solved this problem:

While creating a replica of your query and appending '~'(tilde) to it, retain a copy of the query without the tildes and boost it higher. The number of results remains the same and only the exact matches are ranked higher.

This is the only way that I know of to achieve this with a query modification. If you have found another method, please do share.

Hope this was of help.
EDIT:

```
$searchFields = 'firstName^40 firstName~^20';
```

How ever I can't remember why I stopped using this but from the looks of it, I guess there was a problem putting multiple fields like that in syntax.
Now I use edismax for making searches in multiple fields with different weights and for the above issue i use duplicate fields with different indexing in the schema. Finally give different weights to the respective field names depending on your priority.

Comment: Can you post an example ?